# Make jQueryUI autocomplete height dependent upon parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a jQueryUI autocomplete inside a jQueryUI dialog.  The dialog has a given height (i.e. 200px), and thus the autocomple must have a height less than the dialog so that the scroll bar will be shown.  I've implemented it by hardcoding a 100px height to the autocomplete.  Instead of hardcoding this height, how can I make the height dependent upon the parent's height?

http://jsbin.com/xunazowiqa/1/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Testing</title>  
        <link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            $(function() {
                var availableTags = ["ActionScript","AppleScript","Asp","BASIC","C","C++","Clojure","COBOL","ColdFusion","Erlang","Fortran","Groovy","Haskell","Java","JavaScript","Lisp","Perl","PHP","Python","Ruby","Scala","Scheme"];

                $("#open").click(function() {$("#dialog").dialog("open");});
                $('#dialog').dialog({
                    autoOpen    : false,
                    resizable   : false,
                    height      : 200,
                    width       : 400, 
                    modal       : true,
                    open        : function() {
                        console.log(this,$(this));
                        $(this).find('input').val('')
                        .autocomplete({source: availableTags})
                        .parent().next('ul.ui-autocomplete')
                        .attr('style', 'max-height: 100px; overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden;')
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <button id="open">Open</button>
        <div id="dialog" title="DIALOG TITLE"><input></div>
    </body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To modify heights in jquery use the [.height() function](http://api.jquery.com/height/).

Using this you can read the height of any element and set it based on any calculation you like for another one.

Comment: Thanks kevin.  Changed it to `max-height: '+($t.height()-25)+'px`

Answer (score 2):

you can try like this

```
console.log(this,$(this));
var height = $(this).height();
console.log(height);
$(this).find('input').val('')
.autocomplete({source: availableTags})
.parent().next('ul.ui-autocomplete')
.attr('style', 'max-height: 100px; overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden;')
```

you can put this code in open function
in this code you can get height of dialog box and after you can manage by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

height css propery has an attribute 
`inherit`
*Inherits this property from its parent element.*